# What does rails do after redirect_to or render in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

For example, I have something like this in my controller:

```
def save
  ...
  render 'error' if user.nil?
  @cast = user.cast
  render 'cast'
end
```

I have nil: no method error here (in `user.cast`). But if I use `redirect_to` instead of `render`, everything works perfectly.

It seems like Rails doesn't stop their executive stack after `render`, but stops after `redirect_to`. Doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is correct.  `redirect_to` sends an HTTP 302 redirect message to the user's browser, telling it to go to a different URL, thus stopping your current execution.

I'd reccommend checking out this post:  http://blog.markusproject.org/?p=3313

He gives a great summary of how to use each:

> render will render a particular view using the instance variables
>   available in the action. For example if a render was used for the new
>   action, when a user goes to /new, the new action in the controller is
>   called, instance variables are created and then passed to the new
>   view. Rails creates the html for that view and returns it back to the
>   user’s browser. This is what you would consider a normal page load.
>
> redirect_to will send a redirect to the user’s browser telling it to
>   re-request a new URL. Then the browser will send a new request to that
>   URL and it will go through the action for that URL, oblivious to the
>   fact that it was redirected to. None of the variables created in the
>   action that caused the redirect will be available to the redirected
>   view. This is what happens when you click on ‘Create’ in a form and
>   the object is created and you’re redirected to the edit view for that
>   object.

Answer (score 1):

For your example to work u can change line to

```
render('error') and return if user.nil?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a logger after `render`, for instance. `redirect_to` halts its method execution.